# Stored Procedure INSERT INTO SELECT in MySQL 5.5.62-log version

Tags: mysql

I have to register in `tbl2` all the rows from `tbl1` with the last access `date` for the same `nickname`.

My database is MySQL 5.5.62-log version.

I tried this `Stored Procedure`.

No error, but the inserting on `tbl2` is very long.

Any suggestion for optimize this SP ?

```
BEGIN

DECLARE var INT;

SET var = 0;

WHILE var < 1 DO
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `tbl2` (
                `NickName`,
                `Continent`,
                `Region`,
                `AccessLastDate`
    ) SELECT
        `NickName`,
        `Continent`,
        `Region`,
        `AccessLastDate`
    FROM
        `tbl1` t1
    WHERE
        Continent IN ('Asia','Oceania','Africa')
        AND 
             t1.`AccessLastDate` = (
        SELECT
            MAX(t2.`AccessLastDate`)
        FROM
            `tbl1` t2
        WHERE
            t2.`NickName` = t1.`NickName`
    )
ORDER BY
    t1.`AccessLastDate`;

SET var = var + 1;

END
WHILE;
```

[image]

Comment: The while loop serves no purpose. How well does the select portion of this code perform?

Comment: @P.Salmon Please see the image clumn` TIME` in question, these settings
`SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50000;`
`SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50000;` cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Index on AccessLastDate may help.

Note that adding an index increases insert time and uses more disk space.